# Create a gap between navigation and drop down

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

does somebody know how i can create a little gap between my navigation and the drop down? I tried it with margin without success.

My navigation bar looks like this:

```
<div class="navigation">
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Worker</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="sub">Categories</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Webdesign</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
</ul>
```

I pasted my code to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1oakjjLc/)

I would be appreciate if someone has an idea to solve this.

Comment: Where's the jsfiddle code? You need to click on save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok since it's getting confused in here I decided to open a new answer, here's one way of doing it:

```
.navigation {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: visible;
}

.navigation li {
    height:  60px;
}
```

Basically you push it down by setting the height of the first level li grater than it's container (10px).

http://jsfiddle.net/1oakjjLc/10/

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```css
.menu li:hover ul {margin-top: 10px;}
```

For handling the margin non hover issue:

```css
.menu li:hover ul {padding-top: 10px;}
```

May be try this?

```css
.menu li:hover ul li:first-child {margin-top: 10px;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/1oakjjLc/7/

Comment: Okay that was easy. I tried it before on an other tag. Do you know how to add an little arrow on the top?

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the margin is not hoverable, thus the subnav will close. I suggest you use .menu li:hover ul {border-top: 10px solid white;} but only if you know that the brackground will be white. Otherwise I'd change the markup a little bit and use padding

Comment: Okay the gap is there, but if i go to the drop down with my cursor it close directly.

Comment: @user3700309 Updayed.

Comment: How would you change it?

Comment: Change it to padding! :)

Comment: If i add padding there is no gap and a blue background.

Comment: Use border-top if the site's background is a solid color

Comment: In this case I'm afraid you'll have to change your markup to include a "spacer" element

Comment: Or you can do something like `li:first-child {margin-top: 10px;}`

Comment: And you'll still have the dropdown attached to the nav, just with a little bigger blue area on top

Comment: How do you want it then? @user3700309

Answer (score 0):

```
body > div > ul > li > ul {
border-top: 10px solid white;
}
```

This is if you want it hover-able.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a `div` in your html `<div class="sepLine"></div>` with following css:

```
.sepLine{
    height: 15px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Also remove line-height from this class and add height:

```
.menu a
    {  
        font: 500 15px Open Sans;
        display: block; 
        color: white; 
        height: 50px; /*Change line-height with height*/
        color: #FFF;
        width: 140px;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Final add line-height to this:

```
.menu > li > ul > li > a{
        line-height: 50px; /*Add line height*/
    }
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1oakjjLc/8/)

Entire code:

**html**

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="sepLine"></div>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Worker</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="sub">Categories</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Webdesign</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**css**

```
/* RESET */

html, body, div, span, object, iframe,h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}
body
{
    line-height:1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure, footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section
{ 
    display:block;
}
blockquote, q
{
    quotes:none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after
{
    content:"";
    content:none;
}
a
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul
{
    list-style: none;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
    color: #fff;
}
:-moz-placeholder
{ 
    color: #fff;
    opacity:  1;
}
::-moz-placeholder
{
    color: #fff;
    opacity:  1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder
{
    color: #fff;
}

/* BOX */

*, *:before, *:after
{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* CLEARFIX */

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after
{
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix
{
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* NAVIGATION */

.navigation
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #34495E;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
.menu
{
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
.menu > li
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.menu ul
{ 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
}
.menu a
{  
    font: 500 15px Open Sans;
    display: block; 
    color: white; 
    height: 50px; /*Change line-height with height*/
    color: #FFF;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
.menu a:hover, .menu a:active
{
    color: #1ABC9C;
}
.menu li
{
    list-style: none;
}
.menu li:last-child
{
    float: right;
}
.menu li:hover ul
{
    display: block;
    background: #34536e; 
}
.navigation 
{
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
}
.account
{
    float: right;
}
.sepLine{
    height: 15px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50px;
}

.menu > li > ul > li > a{
    line-height: 50px; /*Add line height*/
}
```